# Можно ли сделать код красивее (много вложеных циклов)

Tags: python, python-3.x, рефакторинг

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def odd_even_counter(in_file, count_letter):
    '''Function: Get a number of symbols if it even or odd in any text file'''    

    odd_counter = 0
    even_counter = 0

    with open(in_file, 'r') as f0:
        phrase_to_check = ''.join([x for x in f0.read() if x.isalpha()])

    for position, item in enumerate(phrase_to_check):
        if item == count_letter:
            if (position + 1) % 2 == 1:
                odd_counter += 1
            else:
                even_counter += 1

    print('Символ [', count_letter, '] на нечетной позиции:', odd_counter, 'раз')
    print('Символ [', count_letter, '] на четной позиции:', even_counter, 'раз')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_file = 'lorem_ipsum.txt' # любой текстовый файл
    test_letter = 'o' # любой символ
    odd_even_counter(test_file, test_letter)
```

Comment: было бы полезно добавить словесное описание того, что код должен делать, чтобы убедиться что он правильно работает.

Answer (score 1):

Следует разделять вычисления и ввод/вывод -- такой код проще, его легче тестировать и повторно использовать.

Вычисления:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Counters = namedtuple('Counters', 'even odd')

def odd_even_counter(text, char):
    """How many times *char* is in even/odd positions in *text*.

    Indexing starts with one.
    """
    counters = [0, 0] # even, odd
    for position, current_char in enumerate(text, start=1):
        if current_char == char:
            counters[position % 2] += 1
    return Counters(*counters)
```

Пример:

```py
>>> odd_even_counter('abbb', 'b')
Counters(even=2, odd=1)
```

Ввод/вывод:

```py
with open('lorem_ipsum.txt') as file:
    letters = (c for line in file for c in line if c.isalpha())
    char = 'o'
    count = odd_even_counter(letters, char)
    print('Символ [ {char} ] на нечётной позиции: {count.odd} раз'.format(**vars()))
    print('Символ [ {char} ] на чётной позиции: {count.even} раз'.format(**vars()))
```

Если необходимо, определение и вычисление `letters` (casefold(), NFKD, grapheme clusters) можно также в отдельную функцию вынести.
Код читает по одной строчке за раз, вместо всего файла целиком.

#### Результат

```py
Символ [ o ] на нечётной позиции: 20 раз
Символ [ o ] на чётной позиции: 18 раз
```